# Program to find out unique elements in a list up to a particular index

Tags: python, list, indexing, unique

Question : Given a list of size N, find out the unique elements in the 
set till a given index K.
input 1 : N : size of set - N
input 2 : K : a partiluar index upto which unique elements need to be find out

```
def dst(N,K,l):

    print(l)
    c=1
    for i in range(1,K):
       a=l[i]
       j=0
       for j in range(i):
            if(a==l[j]):
                break
       if(i==j+1):
            c=c+1 
    print("value of k =")
    print(K)
    print("Count of distinct elements")
    print(c)

l=[]

n=int(input("Enter the limit"))

k=int(input("Enter the value of k"))

for i in range(1,n+1):

    a=int(input("Enter the element"))

    l.append(a)

dst(n,k,l)
```

```
Enter the limit 6  
Enter the value of k 4  
Enter the element 1  
Enter the element 1  
Enter the element 1  
Enter the element 3  
Enter the element 5  
Enter the element 8  
[1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 8]  
value of k = 4

Count of distinct elements
3
```

Original output: 2 ( 1 and 3 are distinct elements till 4th element )

Please can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: try this `len(set(a[:k]))`

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what the `dst()` function should achieve. Given your problem setup, the function should

1. Receive a list
2. Receive an index limit

Given these pieces of information, the function should output the unique elements in the input list up to the specified index limit. The point I'm trying to get across is that the `N` parameter is unnecessary for `dst()`; it is only necessary in so far as building the input list to be fed into `dst()`, which happens outside of the function.

Determining the uniqueness of an element is functionally equivalent to determining whether or not there is a duplicate. One way to go about this would be to declare some output list `res` and append to `res` whenever we see a new element as we loop through the input list up to the specified index. (Here, I interpreted 'up to' as being exclusive, but you could easily edit the function to include the `idx` by doing something like `range(idx + 1)` instead of `range(idx)`.

```py
def unique_elems(idx, lst):
    res = []
    for i in range(idx):
        if lst[i] not in res:
            res.append(lst[i])
    return res
```

Even simpler, if you don't care about the order of the unique elements returned by the function, we could simply convert the sublist into a set, which would effectively get rid of all duplicate elements.

```py
def unique_elems_2(idx, lst):
    return list(set(lst[:idx]))
```

---

Edit: It seems like I might have misconstrued your question. If what you want is the number of unique elements instead of the unique elements themselves, you can simply modify the functions above by returning the `len()` of whatever is being returned. For example,

```py
def n_unique_elems(idx, lst):
    return len(set(lst[:idx]))
```

Comment: This is a nice answer but this doesn't answer the OP question. This leads to alternative solution.

Comment: @Pygirl That's a valid critique. I'll still leave my answer here for OP's reference nonetheless. I hope there is value in letting the OP see a more optimized solution than their current implementation. In a way, it nicely complements your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic was wrong. Instead of counting unique element count duplicate value instead and then substract from `K`

```
def dst(N,K,l):

    print(l)
    d = 0 #<--- Here
    for i in range(1,K):
       a=l[i]
       j=0
       for j in range(i):
            if(a==l[j]):
                d=d+1    #<---- Here            
                break

    print("value of k =")
    print(K)
    print("Count of distinct elements")
    print(K-d)

l=[]

n=int(input("Enter the limit"))

k=int(input("Enter the value of k"))

for i in range(1,n+1):

    a=int(input("Enter the element"))

    l.append(a)

dst(n,k,l)
```

---

**Result1:**

```
Enter the limit6
Enter the value of k3
Enter the element1
Enter the element2
Enter the element3
Enter the element4
Enter the element5
Enter the element6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
value of k =
3
Count of distinct elements
3
```

**Result2:**

```
Enter the limit6
Enter the value of k4
Enter the element1
Enter the element1
Enter the element1
Enter the element3
Enter the element5
Enter the element8
[1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 8]
value of k =
4
Count of distinct elements
2
```

Comment: Can you close the question by accepting the solution that worked?